# Why does Perl's IO::Pipe exception behave differently than croak or die in eval block?

Tags: perl, exception, eval, die

I noticed in my program that an exception raised from IO::Pipe was behaving oddly, and I cannot figure out what it's doing (let alone how it's doing it). I've boiled it down to a simple example program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp;
use IO::Pipe;

my($path) = shift;
my($bad) = shift || "";

eval {
    if ($path =~ m{pipe}i) {
        my($bin) = ($bad ? "/bin/lsddd" : "/bin/ls");

        my($pipe) = IO::Pipe->new();
        $pipe->reader("$bin -l .");
        print "$_" while <$pipe>;
        $pipe->close;
    }
    elsif ($path =~ m{croak}i) {
        croak "CROAKED" if $bad;
    }
    else {
        die "DIED" if $bad;
    }
};

if ($@) {
    my($msg) = $@;

    die "Caught Exception: $msg\n";
}

die "Uh-oh\n" if $bad;

print "Made it!\n";
```

The example program takes two arguments, one to indicate which code path to go down inside the `eval` block, and the second to indicate whether or not to generate an error (anything that evaluates to false will not generate an error). All three paths behave as expected when no error is requested; they all print `Made it!` with no error messages.

When asking for an error and running through the `croak` or `die` paths, it also behaves as I expect: the exception is caught, reported, and the program terminates.

```
$ perl example.pl die foo
Caught Exception: DIED at example.pl line 23.
```

and

```
$ perl example.pl croak foo
Caught Exception: CROAKED at example.pl line 11.
    eval {...} called at example.pl line 10
```

When I send an error down the IO::Pipe path, though, it reports an error, but the program execution continues until the outer `die` is reached:

```
$ perl example.pl pipe foo
Caught Exception: IO::Pipe: Cannot exec: No such file or directory at example.pl line 15.

Uh-oh
```

The first question is why -- why does the program report the "Caught Exception" message but not terminate? The second question is how do I prevent this from happening? I want the program to stop executing if the program can't be run.

Comment: As an aside, I'm using IO::Pipe because I want to collect the output from the program being run along with its exit code, and I want to generate an exception if the command can't be run; if there's a better way to do that, especially one that doesn't present the above problem, please let me know here in the comments.

Comment: There are good modules for collecting output and exit code, from simple to powerful.  Once you have the exit code you can interrogate it and do as you please, and surely throw a `die`. If I understand the purpose right -- run a program and get its output and check exit -- I don't see why to use `IO::Pipe` for that.

Comment: Use [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm generally limited to stock Perl modules. I'll see if an exception(!) can be made for Capture::Tiny. Thanks!

Comment: I can't use Capture::Tiny, as I need to process the output as it occurs (something I forgot to mention). I'll see if there's a way to handle the fork & exec that IO::Pipe is doing. Thanks, again, for the help!

Comment: Then use [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open()-for-IPC) if you only need to read from or write to the external process, but not both; or [IPC::Open3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Open3) or [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) (nicer interface than IPC::Open3 but not in core) if you need to both read from and write to the process.

Comment: If you're just reading from the pipe, then IPC::Open3 will indeed do, and it propagates errors launching the child program into exceptions in the parent as you desired. (I added that very functionality to open3 myself.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure why I wasn't using `open` -- the code was re-written a couple of years ago to use IO::Pipe, but I don't remember why; I'll have to go back through commit comments to see. But switching it (back to) `open` worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I played with this a bit more since I find it curious and found ways to clean up. I updated with the nicest one (test `$?` after `$pipe->close`). But this can't be reliable, and I think that it's best to get out of there. It's a mess, with a loose process running around. Since you say that `Capture::Tiny` doesn't cut it _and_ that the solution should be core, use the good old `open` (or `IPC::Open3` if needed). I removed my previous comment, after I found that `$pipe->error` after `$pipe->close` returns `-1` even when all is well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *two processes* running after the `eval` in the case of interest.  You can see this by adding a print statement before `if ($@)`. One drops through `eval` and thus gets to the last `die`.

The `reader` forks when used with an argument, to open a process. That process is `exec`-ed in the child while the parent returns, with its pid. The code for this is in [`_doit` internal subroutine](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GBARR/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Pipe.pm)

When this fails the child `croak`s with the message you get. But the parent returns regardless as it has no IPC with the child, which is expected to just disappear via `exec`. So the parent escapes and makes its way down the `eval`. That process has no `$@` and bypasses `if ($@)`.

It appears that this is a hole in error handling, in the case when `reader` is used to open a process.

There are ways to tackle this. The `$pipe` is an [IO::Handle](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Handle.html) and we can check it and exit that extra process if it's bad (but simple `$pipe->error` turns out to be the same in both cases). Or, since [close](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html) is involved, we can go to `$?` which is indeed non-zero when error happens

```
# ...
$pipe->close;
exit if $? != 0;
```

(or rather first examine it). This is still a "fix," which may not always work. Other ways to probe the `$pipe`, or to find PID of the escapee, are a bit obscure (or worse, digging into class internals).

On the other hand, a simple way to collect the output and exit code from a program is to use a module for that. A nice pick is [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny). There are others, like [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/IPC-Run-0.94/lib/IPC/Run.pm) and [IPC::Run3](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.048/lib/IPC/Run3.pm), or core but rather low-level [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html).

Given the clarifications, the normal `open` should also be adequate.